# Finish the activity using component name in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to finish one activity from another.
For that purpose I am having **only** the component name of that activity.
How can i finish that ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Make your activity A in manifest file: launchMode = "singleInstance"

2.When the user clicks new, do FirstActivity.fa.finish(); and call the new Intent.

3.When the user clicks modify, call the new Intent or simply finish activity B.

FIRST WAY

In your first activity, declare one Activity object like this,

```
public static Activity fa;
onCreate()

{
fa = this;
}
```

now use that object in another Activity to finish first-activity like this,

```
onCreate()
{
FirstActivity.fa.finish();
}
```

SECOND WAY

While calling your activity FirstActivity which you want to finish as soon as you move on, You can add flag while calling FirstActivity

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

But using this flag the activity will get finished evenif you want it not to. and sometime onBack if you want to show the FirstActivity you will have to call it using intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in very simple way.
First create a static instance of your activity e.g. MainActivity, whom you want to finish like,

```
public static MainActivity act=MainActivity.this;
```

and now in another actvity e.g. MainActivity2 just call this line,

```
MainActivity.act.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extending that activity and override the finish method

```
public class ma extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    public void finish()
    {
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to exit application after log out.
that time to user this

```
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or try to another way like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    finish();
}
```